# Right blocked linear equation solver on Dense Algebra and Sparse Algebra

Tags: numerics, linear-solver, sparse-matrix, hpc, matrix-factorization

I have implemented 1D mesh parallel QR decomposition and LU decomposition,I would like to ask if a linear equation Ax=b,**b is a large matrix** and I need to **shard** b or **Shard** A,b at the same time. Is there any math theory to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "shard" when applied to a matrix? A quick google shows up nothing obviously useful

Comment: Hi,Shard is split matrix  as a block to N-process. for example, 1D Shard ,4-process:A = [A1,A2,A3,A4]. 2d-Shard 4-process: A = [[A1,A2],[A3,A4]. is equal to scalapack standard.So for a problem Ax =B,we need Shard B with LU or blocked-matrix. because B is very large.But I dont found a good theory to do it.

Comment: Scalapack distributes B like that. *All* matrices in Scalapack can be distributed like that

Comment: Thanks to scalapack's work, I'm writing a CPU+GPU numerical algebra library, and I'm hoping to tackle this problem from a theoretical standpoint with my library.The code for slate and magma was so factory-like that I had to write new libraries from theory

Comment: If you are interested in Nvidia hardware have you looked at https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolvermp/ ? But reimplementing dense linear algebra routines can't be the way to go. I suspect explaining why what is available doesn't work for you might be more productive rather than doing it all over again. I have no idea what you mean by "factory-like"

Comment: Factory means that the code is highly modular and difficult to develop twice without being in a development group. I'm currently using an algebra library written in python.I don't think about the cuda implementation, it's too low-level, I'd rather have a unified design.But thanks for the suggestion I'll look into the architecture of cudaSolver.I'm thinking about heterogeneous memory, not just cuda.

Comment: Like @IanBush, I don't understand what your goal is. Why would you re-implement a dense linear algebra library? Is your goal to develop new algorithms? Or to *use* such a library?

Comment: Hi,My goal is to redevelop and unify the design,Because these libraries are so expensive to learn. it's hard for me to learn them.

Comment: I would like to develop a heterogeneous distributed computing library with a simple and transparent underlying interface,user just pip install it.All modules are easy to modify and open source

Comment: @HaitaoXiao The thing is that you cannot have "simple", "transparent", "efficient", and "scalable" all at the same time. If that was possible, the people who write SLATE would have done that.

Comment: I think it's possible.

Comment: @HeitaoXiao All the power to you, we will be happy to see and use the results of your efforts.

Comment: thanks. I will try to do it.OVO